# Solr LRUcache Cause threads to block

Tags: solr

i have legacy java application which use Solr 4 , when i profile the app 
with profiler i see that allot of threads get blocked on LRUcache get/put 
when i check the Solr LRUcache source code i can see that the put/get are both 
synchronized

For example:
PUT

```
@Override
  public V put(K key, V value) {
    synchronized (map) {
      if (getState() == State.LIVE) {
        stats.inserts.increment();
      }
```

GET

```
@Override
  public V get(K key) {
    synchronized (map) {
      V val = map.get(key);
      if (getState() == State.LIVE) {
        // only increment lookups and hits if we are live.
        lookups++;
        stats.lookups.increment();
        if (val!=null) {
          hits++;
          stats.hits.increment();
        }
      }
      return val;
    }
  }
```

Link:
https://github.com/apache/lucene-solr/blob/master/solr/core/src/java/org/apache/solr/search/LRUCache.java

My question is how can i fine tune it to not get blocked in this section of code ?

Comment: Have you tried using the FastLRUCache or the LFUCache instead? Neither have synchronized sections. At least it should give you a good hint whether synchronizing is the actual reason.

Comment: just to replace them in the solrconfig.xml? 
is there any info site that point where and what should i replace/test?

Comment: Yes. The community wiki has a reference page: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Query+Settings+in+SolrConfig

Comment: i did try configure them all day , still performance is bad , and threads get blocked by 
org.apache.lucene.document.LazyDocument.getDocument()
using LFU cache